# MQ 7.0.1.9 selector JMSCorrelationID Mistaken Msg

Tags: jms, mq

We developed an Java application in which multiple Java JMS clients connect to a server, both with Websphere MQ 7.0.1.9. Each client has consumer with selector on application specific client id eg. JMSCorrelationID='050_14133431' on shared queues, in which server set application specific client id on messages by setJMSCorrelationID( ) sent to a particular client. Application specifi client ids are unique. It works fine most of the time. However, we just found some messages with client A sessionId are consumed by client B surprisingly. I checked the logs and confirmed that each client only create consumer with selector on its sessionId. In my understanding, consumer with only consume messages that match the selector criteria. One thing to note is that I used read ahead feature as our application use non persistent messages. This happened very rarely, say once a month. Any idea why this happen? Any syntax error in JMSCorrelationID='050_14133431', should it must start with letter instead of digit? Any hints are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Consumer will get only those messages that match selection criteria. Which JMS Provider(or Messaging Server) are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I see the title, you are using IBM MQ.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below JMS documentation (Emphasis mine):

> The delivery modes supported by the JMS API are PERSISTENT and
>   NON_PERSISTENT.
>
> A client marks a message as persistent if it feels that the
>   application will have problems if the message is lost in transit. A
>   client marks a message as non-persistent if an occasional lost message
>   is tolerable. Clients use delivery mode to tell a JMS provider how to
>   balance message transport reliability with throughput.
>
> Delivery mode covers only the transport of the message to its
>   destination. Retention of a message at the destination until its
>   receipt is acknowledged is not guaranteed by a PERSISTENT delivery
>   mode. Clients should assume that message retention policies are set
>   administratively. Message retention policy governs the reliability of
>   message delivery from destination to message consumer. For example, if
>   a client's message storage space is exhausted, some messages may be
>   dropped in accordance with a site-specific message retention policy.
>
> **A message is guaranteed to be delivered once and only once by a JMS
>   provider if the delivery mode of the message is PERSISTENT** and if the
>   destination has a sufficient message retention policy.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/DeliveryMode.html

*In Summary, If the message is marked as NON_PERSISTENT, then JMS provider can't guarantee once and only once delivery. If it is not acceptable, you should change it to PERSISTENT mode.*

Also, you should perform a resilience (non-functional) tests (with scenarios like Broker fail overs, etc..) with Production volumes of messages, to find out the average number of duplicate messages.